# How to test drag and drop behavior in PyQt?

Tags: qt, testing, pyqt

I want to unittest drag and drop for our widgets. At the moment, I instantiate a QDragEnterEvent, but this is discouraged with a big warning on the Qt documentation, because it relies on the Qt library internal state. In fact, I get segfaults that appear to be due to a violation of this Warning.

Given this premise, how can one test drag and drop behavior?

Answer (score 6):

**If using Unix we can use QTest, however to get a cross-platform solution, we can implement a solution where we circumvent Qt.**

### Using QTest

Although the Qt documentation for [drag and drop](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dnd.html#dragging) says that it will not block the main event loop, a closer look at [`QDrag.exec`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdrag.html#exec) will reveal that this is not true for Windows.

The call to [`QTest.mousePress`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtest.html#mouseMove) causes the test to block until the mouse is physically moved by the user.

I got around this in Linux by using a timer to schedule the mouse move and release:

```
def testDragAndDrop(self):
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, self.dropIt)
    QtTest.QTest.mousePress(dragFromWidget, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)

    # check for desired behaviour after drop
    assert something

def dropIt(self):
    QtTest.QTest.mouseMove(dropToWidget)
    QtTest.QTest.mouseRelease(dropToWidget, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, delay=15)
```

For this solution, it is necessary to include a delay in the `mouseRelease` call, and to have called `show` on your widget.

Note that I have verified this works using pyqt4 and Python 2.7 on Fedora 20

### Cross-Platform

**You can use the mouse manipulation methods from the [PyUserInput](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyUserInput) package. Put the mouse interaction in separate thread to avoid the locking up of the Qt main event loop**. We can do this since we are not using Qt at all in our mouse control. Make sure that you have called `show` on the widgets you are dragging to/from.

```
from __future__ import division
import sys, time, threading
import numpy as np

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtTest
from pymouse import PyMouse
...

def mouseDrag(source, dest, rate=1000):
    """Simulate a mouse visible mouse drag from source to dest, rate is pixels/second"""
    mouse = PyMouse()
    mouse.press(*source)

    # smooth move from source to dest
    npoints = int(np.sqrt((dest[0]-source[0])**2 + (dest[1]-source[1])**2 ) / (rate/1000))
    for i in range(npoints):
        x = int(source[0] + ((dest[0]-source[0])/npoints)*i)
        y = int(source[1] + ((dest[1]-source[1])/npoints)*i)
        mouse.move(x,y)
        time.sleep(0.001)

    mouse.release(*dest)

def center(widget):
    midpoint = QtCore.QPoint(widget.width()/2, widget.height()/2)
    return widget.mapToGlobal(midpoint)

def testDragAndDrop(self):
    # grab the center of the widgets
    fromPos = center(dragFromWidget)
    toPos = center(dropToWidget)

    dragThread = threading.Thread(target=mouseDrag, args=((fromPos.x(),fromPos.y()), (toPos.x(), toPos.y())))
    dragThread.start()
    # cannot join, use non-blocking wait
    while dragThread.is_alive():
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(1000)

    # check that the drop had the desired effect
    assert dropToWidget.hasItemCount() > 0
```

Note I have tested this using PyQt4 and Python 2.7 on Fedora and Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried, but if your drag & drop process is Qt internal (meaning, you're dragging from and to a Qt widget), [QTest](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtest.html) might help.

Basically by doing something along the lines:

```
QTest.mousePress(drag_widget, Qt.LeftButton) # simulate mouse press on whatever you want to drag
QTest.mouseMove(drop_widget) # move the mouse to the target - maybe this can be skipped
QTest.mouseRelease(drop_widget, Qt.LeftButton) # simulate mouse release where you want to drop
```

All functions may be supplied with further positional information (e.g. to click a list item within a widget) and with optional delays to emulate a human user.

Not a copy-pasteable answer, but maybe it serves as a starter...

Comment: What you posted is very interesting, and I will take a look at it, thanks. The only problem I encounter usually with these methods is that they require exact positionings and offsets, and I found that this is rather unstable (for example, if another window is present on the test machine desktop). In any case, it's probably the official way to go.

Comment: I'd like to upvote but I would rather know whether or not it works. If @Stefano can test and post result, I'd be glad to upvote.

Comment: This does not work - I've tried on Windows 8.1 with Qt 5.4.2.  The mouseMove() creates a mouse event with no buttons - that may be the problem.

Comment: Working on exactly the same problem. This proposed solution sadly does not work, I've tried on Xubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with Qt 5.2.1.